# How to compare date if one column has start and end date

Tags: mysql, database

The column has a start and end date

```
month_name
23 March, 2018 - 23 April, 2018
```

23 March, 2018 is the `start date` and 23 April, 2018 is the `end date`

How can I use them as to the start date and end date to query?

Comment: In that case a redesign of the database would seem like the best solution so you dont make it difficult to process your data

Comment: Yes, I understand your point..but on this point ,i can't do this, I would request to please provide any solution.

Comment: You will have to start looking at the [string manipulations functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) provided by MySQL

Comment: And also the [Date manipulations functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: `select STR_TO_DATE('23 March, 2018', '%d %M,%Y');` to help you starting.... 

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) to return a part of the string to the left or right of the hyphen. But this would be **terrible in terms of performance**. So you need to look at your data structure and redesign accordingly. The start and end dates should be in distinct columns with an INDEX and appropriate DATATYPE set ([DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)).

I would suggest that you process the text prior to saving to the database, by using client language regex or split/substring functionality to correctly format the dates into MYSQL format before saving.

Answer (score 1):

```
set @fromto='23 March, 2018 - 23 April, 2018'; 
select 
  str_to_date(left(@fromto,locate('-',@fromto)-1),'%d %M,%Y') datefrom,
  str_to_date(right(@fromto,length(@fromto)-locate('-',@fromto)),'%d %M,%Y') dateto;
```

output:

```
+------------+------------+
| datefrom   | dateto     |
+------------+------------+
| 2018-03-23 | 2018-04-23 |
+------------+------------+
```

short explanation:

1. set @fromto - defines a variable, which is used as input for this example
2. locate('-',@fromto)  - this will find the length of the part in @fromto before the '-', the -1 is needed because where only want the part before the '-'
3. length(@fromto)-locate('-',@fromto) - this will find the length of the part in @fromto after the '-'
4. str_to_date(...)  - see [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Could you edit your answer and explain what is going on? Thanks

Comment: added a short explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For each and every query that would need to use these dates, you would have to unpick one or both of these dates that are relevant to the query using this kind of text and date  manipulation

```
SELECT .....
WHERE whatever_else
AND STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(monthname, ' -', 1 ), '%d %M,%Y') = '2018-03-23' 
AND STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(monthname, INSTR(monthname, '- ') +2 ), '%d %M,%Y') = '2018-04-23'
```

In short your queries would be a complete nightmare to write and maintain and any indexing benefits you might have been able to use had these 2 dates been saved in 2 seperate columns are completely lost.

> [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)
>
> [SUBSTRING()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)
>
> [INSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)
>
> [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)